# When doing regression modeling on the absolute difference between pairs, how to define features?

Tags: regression, feature-engineering, predictor, differences

Let's say I want to do regression on dependent variable `y` with several features `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`. My data is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv')
df

y      A     B      C      D      E
2.3    1     22     52     1      23
5.3    2     15     8.5    1.5    21
4.7    5     99     8.3    1.3    21
1.2    6     1      3.5    1.2    22.5
....
```

So, we would run our favorite regression model on this to predict `y`.

Now, let's say I want to create a regression model to predict the difference of `y` between pairs of y.

```
pair1 = 2.3 - 5.3 = 3
pair2 = 2.3 - 4.7 = 2.4
pair3 = 2.3 - 1.2 = 1.1
...
```

So I am predicting the absolute difference between each unique pair of data points.

Question: what does one do with the features? Do you take the mean between two datapoints, or perhaps take the difference as well?